# Grease pencil / 2D drawing in cycles?

Tags: animation, cycles-render-engine, grease-pencil, 2d

I made an animation that is supposed to be rendered in cycles.
Now i'll like to add some 2D animation, impact smoke and such.

But i can see grease pencil doesn't render in Cycles.
Is there any work around this?

I seen you can turn it into a curve, and make it thicker.
But then i have no fill color, and it's a very slow workflow.

I could also make the animation in procreate, but i'm not sure if i can get it into Blender with a transparent background.

But it would just be much easier if i could draw an animation directly in blender and render it in Cycles.

I also thought about adding the 2D animation after, but some of the drawings is behind the 3D objects. So it would really be a pain to draw around or mask path of the objects.

EDIT:
It seems to be the Denoiser that is the problem. So either i'll have to do without it, or try to find some kind of workaround.

So any suggestions would be appreciated.

Link to my Denoise setup
https://i.stack.imgur.com/9YByN.jpg

I'm kinda inspired by the "Just a dash" intro.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is a mesh + a Grease pencil object, rendered in Cycles.

[image]

Comment: Oh you are completely right, thank you, my bad for not checking in default. I figured out it's because i use Denoise, so either i'll have to do it without Denoise, or there is a workaround, any suggestions? https://imgur.com/a/eNSd10i